# Plot German states using geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I need to plot German states using geopandas.

Where could I find `.shp` file for Germany which has either state/city borders?

Comment: [jan-46106.medium.com/plotting-maps-with-european-data-in-python](https://jan-46106.medium.com/plotting-maps-with-european-data-in-python-part-i-decd83837de4) is a pretty good tutorial; it plots with geopandas and .json, not .shp.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

If you type in Google: "german states shapefile", you will get this result:

https://www.igismap.com/download-germany-shapefile-free-boundary-line-polygon-shapefile/

After you download a shapefile, you read it like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile/shapefile.shp")
```

Comment: Thank you Marjan for providing the information. I was able to get the outline of Germany as map but could not find the regions/cities separation. Could you please point me how to visualize 16 states of Germany. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a link to the states shapefile in the middle of the page I have linked... Keep in mind that finding the source data has nothing to do with geopandas and python...

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose a source, for more details check [this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192993/where-can-i-find-state-borders-for-germany), e.g. [DIVA-GIS | Administrative](http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown) where you need `'DEU_adm1.shp'`
2. Try the code below

   ```
   import io
   import zipfile
   import requests
   import geopandas as gpd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   local_path = 'tmp/'
   url = "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/DEU_adm.zip"

   r = requests.get(url)
   z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
   z.extractall(path=local_path)

   gdf = gpd.read_file(local_path + '/DEU_adm1.shp')
   gdf.plot(color='white',
            edgecolor='black')
   plt.show()
   ```

and get the output

[image: result]

For more details check this article [Reading Shapefile ZIPs from a URL in Python 3](https://medium.com/@loldja/reading-shapefile-zips-from-a-url-in-python-3-93ea8d727856)